# Variable not appearing when debugging scala code with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

I try to debug a Scala program using IntelliJ's debugger. I'm wondering why the variable `newx` is not listed in the "Variables"-panel of the debugger:

[image]

I'm especially surprised because newx is not a `lazy val`. Is it omitted because it is never referenced later in the code and therefore garbage-collected?

Comment: did you try using it somewhere below definition, may be compiler just optimising it

Comment: yes, if I use the variable below definition then it appears in the variables-panel

Answer (score 2):

Scala compiler's optimization deletes it because you are not using it. 
You can see it by using it below or just use `evaluate expression` feature of Idea and type variable name and run, it will probably find it.